# Issues with sklearn.svm.SVC

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to use the sklearn.svm.SVC on a relatively big dataset, 1.5k test/train samples, 512 features each, one sample per class (so, 1.5k classes). I know that SVC doesn't scale well, so at first I tried LinearSVC, but it didn't achieve the required quality. So, I decided to fit an RBF/polynomial kernel, and utilise parallelism as much as possible to reduce computation time. I have attempted the following:

1. Use a plain SVC(kernel='rbf'). This approach failed immediately, since calling decision_function somehow required 200Gb of RAM.
2. Wrap SVC in a OneVsRest classifier, which significantly reduced the required memory. This works, but it utilizes all 16 CPUs only in the beginning (during fit would be my guess), after which it gets stuck at one worker (according to htop: total workload drops from 1600% to 100%). I believe the culprit is the decision_function.

To achieve method 1 I use

```
model = SVC().fit(X_train, Y_train)
decision_scores = model.decision_function(X_test)
```

For method 2:

```
with joblib.parallel_backend('loky'):
    model = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(**self.kwargs)).fit(gallery_feats, gallery_ids)
    decision_scores = model.decision_function(probe_feats)
```

So, my question is, how does one parallelize the decision_function call? Or, alternatively, how to reduce the memory footprint of SVC().decision_function? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `SVC` and not other models?

Comment: SVMs are known memory hogs. As @spectre said, maybe you actually need to consider other models.

Comment: @liakoyras thank you for your insights! I wanted to try out, how effective svms would be. Yes, seems that other models are the way to go here. Would you kindly attach some links on svm memory efficiency?

Comment: I don't have anything in particular in mind. I am mostly speaking from experience, SVMs are famously inefficient. A quick google search will come up with a lot of results.

Comment: @liakoyras thank you anyway!